# Load a Swift based ViewController from Objective C class's button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, action

**Note**: It is not a duplicate one to any question. I could not find any question with some action method and creating an instance for a swift based view controller.

I am calling a swift based view controller in objective c class .m file.

In my `ViewController.m` I have imported bridge header

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Project-Bridging-Header.h"
```

**I want to call Swift based view controller from the below action**

```
- (IBAction)tappedButnGo:(UIButton *)sender {

     SwiftViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SwiftViewController"];
}
```

Here I am getting an error

> use of undeclared identifier SwiftViewController

and below is swift class

```
import UIKit

@objc class SwiftViewController: UIViewController {
 //so on
```

and my `BridgingHeader` is empty.

Can anyone help me on loading `SwiftViewController` when I click on `Objective C'`s button action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `import` following statement in your `Controller.h` file

```
#import "ProductModuleName-swift.h"
```

Here `PrductModuleName` is your project name

Hope this will help you

Comment: `#import "AutoLayout-Swift.h"`, AutoLayout is my project name.

Comment: How can it allow me to import when there is no file with `projectname-swift.h`. It is throwing same error `file not found`

Comment: where have you write statement?

Comment: I am importing it in `ViewController.m` which is Obj-c class.

Comment: @NiravD, my project name is X-Ample so how can i do this...? and also im getting the file not found error when  X-Ample-swift.h or  XAmple-swift.h

Comment: @AbiramiBala Try once like `#import "X_Ample.h"` if it still not work then you can find your run time generated `Swift.h` file name in the `Build Setting` search for `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` and use that one check [this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcteY.png).

Comment: @Nirav X_Ample-swift.h worked for me..., Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 5):

Check the storyboard `SwiftViewController` identifier like following image you need to set `StoryBoard` ID of your `SwiftViewController` from identiry Inspector :

Following is a steps to use swift class in objective c project:

- Create New project and select Objective C language.
- After that when you create new class at that time you get the popup like:

[image]

- Create Bridge header and then go to the build setting and search with **Defines Module** and make its value `YES`
- Now you need to create your `swiftVeiwControllers` identifire like following code and go to the first viewcontroller

  [image]
- Now you need to import **#import "obj_swift-Swift.h"**. here **obj_swift** is your project name so its look like `#import "yourprojectname-Swift.h"`

---

That's it now you just need to do code like following:

```
- (IBAction)PushSwift:(id)sender {

     SwiftViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SwiftViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

**Here is the sample demo code:**

https://github.com/nitingohel/obj_swift

Comment: not working, still it is showing the same error. I am unable to create an instance to my swiftclass to use it.

Comment: Thanks bro, I think , in `#import "yourprojectname-Swift.h"` here `s(swift)` is small.

Comment: Its working without small also, but I have a doubt here, with small only the above answer is working, why?

Comment: i think that not case sensitive

Comment: But If I keep it `Swift`, throwing file not found error.

Comment: @NitinGohel, i found your demo in that too the file not found erroris showing. my project name is X-Ample so how can i do this...? and also im getting the file not found error when X-Ample-swift.h or XAmple-swift.h

Answer (score 0):

I quite came up with a different situation where used Xib files instead of view controllers:

If some is looking for it, this will be the correct method:

1. Create a new `CocoaTouchClass` with `xib` file: [image]
2. Assign `Restoration ID` to the Xib file
   [image]
3. Put bridging header file as others have mentioned earlier in this question. "`Project Target Name-Bridging-Header.h`"
4. import that header to the objective c class file.
5. Use following code to call to the Xib file.

   `UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SwiftViewControllerNibRestorationID" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Here `ActivityFollowViewController` is my `SwiftViewControllerNibRestorationID`